# Identify these Warhammer creatures

Tags: character-identification, warhammer-fantasy

In a recent [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC1Y2pFP2ls) for *[Total War: Warhammer](https://warhammer.totalwar.com/)*, we see these creatures of [Chaos](https://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos) for a brief moment. I don't recognize them.

Can anyone tell me who or what they are?

[image: screenshot showing the creatures, looking a bit like armoured dogs]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe these handsome fellows are Gorebeasts.

[image: a photo of a painted miniature of a gorebeast pulling a chariot]